# Suavizar textos em CSS

Tags: html, css, font

sei que é impossível fazer com que os textos sejam exibidos de maneira uniforme em todos os navegadores, mas estou com o problema abaixo que está me incomodando um pouco, apesar de nas imagens não parecer muito, no chrome a fonte fica com as bordas "picotadas";

> Firefox:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Chrome

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Testei com as fontes Ebrima, Helvetica e Bebas, as 3 ficam igualmente "picotadas" no chrome, já testei metódos como

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Mas o chrome insiste em deixar as fontes feias, existe algum metódo ou uma boa fonte para impedir que isso aconteça?